# fadeIn fadeOut by asp.net button

Tags: asp.net

I have this html code :

```
        function ToggleMenu() {
            $('#Menu').fadeOut(500);
        }
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="Menu">
        <a  class="MainMenu" href="#" onclick="DoSomething()">Fun</a>

        <div id="Dropdown">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat='server' Text="Toggle Menu" OnClientClick="ToggleMenu()" />
    </form>
</body>
```

I used `OnClientClick` attr for `asp:Button` To Fade Menu, but it fades out and then after a postback it fades in again, what should am i do ?

Answer (score 1):

Any changes made in the client are not automatically persisted to the server.  Since the server didn't know it was hidden, it won't react to the change.  There is an easy workaround.  Add a hidden field:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="Button1Status" runat="server" />
```

On hiding the button, add this JS code:

```
$("#<%= Button1Status.ClientID %>").val("1");
```

Then on the server, on every postback, check if the hidden field is "1", and if it is, set `Visible="false"` or `style="display:none"` so that ViewState can retain this setting.  Note: if you set `Visible="false"`, the button won't render at all.

Comment: another way.? note : i want to fade out a div by a asp button.

Comment: If you want the change persisted on the server, you have to use a hidden field to store the state change.  Hiddens post back to the server, therefore can retain their state using viewstate.  If you want to fade out a DIV, you can store the current state of the DIV, and the hidden can be used for current status.  Therefore, when the page reloads, on document ready or from code behind, you can reinitialize the visibility of the div based on this hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

you need to disable post back.

```
function ToggleMenu() { 
    $('#Menu').fadeOut(500); 
    return false;
}
```

"return false" will prevent from posting back.

alternatively if you don't need server side functionality then use simple html input element and assign onclick function.

Comment: sorry, I missed the fact you want to maintain the state. Brians solution looks fine then. you need to have a server side flag which would remember state.